# Can a .NET Core app on Windows also access system.web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

We have a large ASP.NET application, that we are working to move toward .NET Core. The main goal is to self host (bye bye IIS, hello xcopy deploy!).

We have a path to migrate the app to Razor (several hundred aspx files), and this looks good (we were mostly on MVC, so we only have a few old legacy-asp.net pieces which we are redoing to MVC).

However, we have a large stack of third party libs that are .NET 4.6 based. We are stuck with most of these libs. These libs are hard coded to system.web for a number of functions. We cannot change this.

So the question: If I stick to running my .NET Core animal on Windows, can I, in process, also reference .NET 4.6/4.7 ?

(No, we are not going to microservices, please don't propose that.)

Comment: referencing .NET 4.6/4.7 under .NET core = out of luck. Works the other way around though

Comment: Works the other way.... so I can be a .NET 4.6 app and self host kestrel web server?

Comment: @Steve , see note above,

Comment: A web app built for .net core can run on top of .NET framework without a problem. But a web app built for .NET framework or uses libraries thats incompatible with .net core can't run on .net core. hopefully that's clear enough. Think of .net core as a slim version of full .NET

Comment: @Steve No, .NET Core can't run on .NET Framework. However, a web application for ASP.NET Core can run on .NET Core or .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core and .NET Core are different things.

Comment: Why do you think you can't xcopy deploy an application built for .NET Framework?

Comment: @mason So.... can I build a .net core app that is a web server, self hosting kestrel, that runs on full .NET Framework, with libs that are pure .Net Framework libs?

Comment: @mason Sorry, what I mean is that an asp.net app cannot be JUST xcopied because there is a bunch of IIS config to do. We are working toward a pure xcopy deploy, to eliminate IIS futzing.

Comment: Script it out - it's only painful if you're doing it manually.

Comment: @mason We have deliberately avoided scripting IIS setup. %80 of our stack (all C# code) can be deployed and installed via xcopy (it is all windows services). We are working to make that %100.  We like tools that have simple config files. We find IIS to require too much "special attention" and , though it is a super powerful web server, we will sacrifice the power in order to gain "redistribution simplicity"   IOW, if we have to deploy six servers instead of three, we will pay that price to make our app easier to deploy, and to shorten our tech dependency chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core are a set of libraries that run on both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

This means you can create an ASP.NET Core application that runs on .NET Framework and keep using all the stuff that is in .NET Framework. This can be done by creating a new ASP.NET Core application and editing the `.csproj` file to set `TargetFramework` from e.g. `netcoreapp2.0` to `net472` and replacing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage with individual NuGet packages containing the ASP.NET Core libraries (`Microsoft.AspNetCore` etc.).

While this also gives you access to using types in System.Web, this may not be useful since the ASP.NET Core application does not run in IIS, so e.g. HttpContext from System.Web cannot be used (since there is no IIS/ASP.NET HTTP context).

So bottom line, it depends on what functionality of System.Web the libraries you are using depend on.