# Can a .NET Core app, self hosting razor web app on Kestrel, run on full .NET and reference system.web?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

This thought process started in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535644/147637).

What we are doing:

- Converting a large asp.net app to razor (several hundred pages and templates)

  -- this part is done

What we want to do next: Self host the web site in [kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

The question: This app uses a LOT of third party libs that require full .NET Framework on windows, including lots of references to system.web.

In a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535644/147637), it is indicated that we can have a .NET Core project run on full .NET Framework.

If that is true, can this .NET Core project, which will self host using kestrel, also include full, "old" .NET 4.6 assemblies that use system.web?

Comment: Running ASP.NET Core apps on .NET Framework supports very limited scenarios, where you can consume a specific set of old assemblies (ADP.NET providers and so on). I don't think assemblies that rely on `System.Web` (aka ASP.NET 4.x) can be used this way, as ASP.NET Core itself has a different programming model, and many things would easily break. Again, assert each of the assemblies (you did not show what they were).

Comment: Most, or maybe even all, asp.net core libraries target .NET Standard, not .NET Core. That means they can be used by applications targeting .NET Core, or full .NET Framework, or anything else that support .NET Standard set of apis, without any problems. So, if you are running on windows only - just use full .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a comment on this post, it is indicated that we can have a .NET Core project run on full .NET Framework.

This idea is wrong and I am not sure which comment made you think of this. Either it is .NET Core or it is .NET Framework. You can host ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework or .NET Core, but that's another story.

> If that is true, can this .NET Core project, which will self host using kestrel, also include full, "old" .NET 4.6 assemblies that use system.web?

No, you cannot, since that is **not** true. You *can*, however, have an ASP.NET Core application running on .NET Framework 4.6 that uses `System.Web` references, but this has many limits; for example, you cannot run ASP.NET OWIN pipelines on ASP.NET Core. It all depends on what specifically you need to use from `System.Web` and its related assemblies.

---

However, let me make this as clear as possible:

## .NET Core != ASP.NET Core

Comment: "You can, however, have an ASP.NET Core application running on .NET Framework 4.6 that uses System.Web references." I doubt that part. It should be verified in a case-by-case way.

Comment: @LexLi I hope that edit makes it clearer what I meant

Comment: Camilo, thank you very much. This area needs, I think, a detailed write up somewhere. The question I have for you is: If I can have an ASP.NET Core application running on .NET Framework 4.6, can this ASP.NET Core app : Self host in Kestrel (e.g. no IIS) _and_ include legacy .NET assemblies (understanding that access to the IIS message pipeline, OWIN, and other aspects won't work because IIS is not present)?

Comment: @Jonesome Yes, that's what my answer meant. Not sure what specifically would work and what wouldn't, that probably needs some trial and error

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you again. We know are headed into trial and error land.... But first we have to arrive. Thank you for pointing the way!

Comment: @Jonesome You are welcome, please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers